# Host my own chrome extension in my website

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have developed one chrome extension and i want to use it on some windows pc's all over the world (of course the owners know me and my work)

but i dont want to upload it on WEBSTORE since its only for something we use for ourselfs.

Could i host the extension on my own website ???
I've searched some things but it says from chrome 33 you can not.

I want to host it so when i will update the files, it should be automatically updated to all of my friends windows pc's from my website.

Does anyone has any idea of what can i do ???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can put it on the webstore, but mark it as "unlisted" so that only those who have the extension id can get to it.  Would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, no, since Chrome 33 you can't have auto-updating extensions that are not Web Store hosted.

As Teepeemm mentions, you don't have to be publicly visible on the Store catalog: you can publish as "unlisted".

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Pass along the crx to users, and have them manually install it via chrome://extensions.  This requires users to be in developer mode, however, which most users won't want to be.
2. Upload it privately to the chrome store and have them use inline installation: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation

Chrome specifically doesn't allow any other options to prevent extensions from being used to install malware on a users computer.